# settings colordialog.customcolor to equal form background color

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i am trying to set one of the custom colors of the colordialog to be the current background color of the form. i am doing it like this:

```
ColorDialog1.CustomColors(0) = Form1.BackColor.ToArgb
```

it is not working. please help! vb.net code please

please note that i only need a specific element to contain the color. not necessarily 0, but perhaps 9 or 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getter for the `CustomColors` property of `ColorDialog` returns a clone of the array of custom colours, so doing what you have in your question will be modifying a copy of the array, not the one used by the dialog.

To set just a single custom colour, get the value of the `CustomColors` property and assign it to a variable. Change the colours by altering the items in this variable. Once done, set the value of this variable back to the `CustomColors` property.

As chrissr says (and the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.colordialog.customcolors.aspx) docs), the default value for this is `null`, so you might have to assign a new array. I tried it in Visual Studio though, and the `CustomColors` did contain a fully populated array of white.